# Why final and abstract only modifiers can be used with a local inner class in java?

Tags: java

HI
I like to know why final and abstract modifiers used for local inner class in java....
Can anybody elaborate on this?

Comment: Is it local or is it inner? Those are not the same thing.

Comment: You can also declare inner classes as static also.

Comment: To be clear, a local inner class is an inner class defined within a method.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great example of the usage of abstract inner classes at o'reilly, please look at look at the 'hierarchies of inner classes' section:

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/HardcoreJava_chap06/index.html

Answer (score 1):

It does not matters if your class is local, inner or top level class. You can use only either of abstract or final modifiers with all of them but not both.

.

When you use `abstract` modifier for class, it means:

1. Class is partially implemented and
   there will be sub-class of this
   class which will give complete
   implementation
2. You cannot instantiate abstract
   class
3. You can have zero or more abstract
   methods in abstract class (abstract
   method is an method whose
   implementation is not known)

.

When you use `final` modifier for class, it means:

1. Class is fully implemented and there
   should not be any sub-class of this
   class.
2. **Modifier final is totally opposite
   of abstract modifier. Hence for a
   class, final and abstract modifier
   cannot be used together**.

**Reference:**

8.1.1.1 abstract Classes:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#34944

8.1.1.2 final Classes:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#54727

Answer (score 0):

Because you can extend an inner class.  For detail, read [here](http://java.sys-con.com/node/35776).  You would define final to help the reader understand your code better.  You would make abstract inner class for the same reasons you would make a regular abstract class.